# Laravel - how to change table in orWhere method?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to do something like this:

```
$posts= Status::where('users_id',$user->id)->orWhere(DB::table('user_status_share.user_id', $user->id))->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

But I'm getting an error: **strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given** - how can I change the table in "orWhere" method? Is this possible? If not - how to use 2 tables in one query?

**Schema (Status):**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users_status', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unique();
        $table->longText('status_text');
        $table->integer('users_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users_status');
}
```

**Schema (StatusShare):**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('user_status_share', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('status_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('user_status_share');
}
```

**Model Status:**

```
namespace App\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Status extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'users_status';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StatusComments::class);
    }

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StatusLikes::class);
    }

    public function shares()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StatusShare::class);
    }

}
```

**Model StatusShare:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StatusShare extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $table = 'user_status_share';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Status::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get data from both tables?

Comment: Please post your schema structure and the data format you are expecting in the output.

Comment: Yes, I want to take data from 2 tables

Comment: Schema added. I'm expecting array

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this

tweak it , i didnt test it

```
 $posts = DB::table('status')->where('users_id',$user->id)->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->table('user_status_share')->where('user_id', $user->id);
            })
            ->get();
```

can you share more informations because i have a feeling that these can be reached in a simple way using relations (show us database structure and relations in your models)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this gives me an error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()".